# why space between N500 and \le too large?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, cases

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-16 \le &N_{500} \le -8.88 \times 10^{-16} \\
-4 \le &N_{501} \le 24 \\
-6.94 \times 10^{-17} \le &N_{502} \le 2.78 \times 10^{-16} \\
-24 \le &N_{511} \le 4\\
-2.78 \times 10^{-16} \le &N_{512} \le 6.94 \times 10^{-17} \\
&D_{500}=4\\
-1 \le &D_{501} \le 0\\
2.78 \times 10^{-7} \le &D_{511} \le 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code uses environment `array` to control the spacing. Instead of `cases` a simple `\left\{...\right.` is used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{@{\,}l@{\;}l@{}}
-16 \le &N_{500} \le -8.88 \times 10^{-16} \\
-4 \le &N_{501} \le 24 \\
-6.94 \times 10^{-17} \le &N_{502} \le 2.78 \times 10^{-16} \\
-24 \le &N_{511} \le 4\\
-2.78 \times 10^{-16} \le &N_{512} \le 6.94 \times 10^{-17} \\
&D_{500}=4\\
-1 \le &D_{501} \le 0\\
2.78 \times 10^{-7} \le &D_{511} \le 1
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or with a right-aligned first column:

```
\begin{array}{@{\,}r@{\;}l@{}}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Is there any possibility to make sure the left \le (<=) are in the same column

Answer (score 2):

[image]

`cases` makes two left aligned columns the intention is not to put the & after the operator as you have it but to put the entire formula in the first column and then after the & have the condition in which each case applies. Here I use `aligned`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}




cases
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-16 \le &N_{500} \le -8.88 \times 10^{-16} \\
-4 \le &N_{501} \le 24 \\
-6.94 \times 10^{-17} \le &N_{502} \le 2.78 \times 10^{-16} \\
-24 \le &N_{511} \le 4\\
-2.78 \times 10^{-16} \le &N_{512} \le 6.94 \times 10^{-17} \\
&D_{500}=4\\
-1 \le &D_{501} \le 0\\
2.78 \times 10^{-7} \le &D_{511} \le 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}






aligned
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
-16 \le &N_{500} \le -8.88 \times 10^{-16} \\
-4 \le &N_{501} \le 24 \\
-6.94 \times 10^{-17} \le &N_{502} \le 2.78 \times 10^{-16} \\
-24 \le &N_{511} \le 4\\
-2.78 \times 10^{-16} \le &N_{512} \le 6.94 \times 10^{-17} \\
&D_{500}=4\\
-1 \le &D_{501} \le 0\\
2.78 \times 10^{-7} \le &D_{511} \le 1
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `alignedat` or `array`. In both cases, I recommend usage of `siunitx` for the numbers in scientific format.

In the top implementation, the lower bounds are aligned right and the upper bounds are aligned left; in the bottom realization, the numbers are aligned at the decimal point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\num{-16}       & \le {} & N_{500} & \le \num{-8.88e-16} \\
\num{-4}        & \le {} & N_{501} & \le \num{24}        \\
\num{-6.94e-17} & \le {} & N_{502} & \le \num{2.78e-16}  \\
\num{-24}       & \le {} & N_{511} & \le \num{4}         \\
\num{-2.78e-16} & \le {} & N_{512} & \le \num{6.94e-17}  \\
                &        & D_{500} & =   \num{4}         \\
\num{-1}        & \le {} & D_{501} & \le \num{0}         \\
\num{2.78e-7}   & \le {} & D_{511} & \le \num{1}
\end{alignedat}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{
  S[table-format=-2.2e-2]
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  c
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  S[table-format=-1.2e-2]
}
-16       & \le & N_{500} & \le & -8.88e-16 \\
-4        & \le & N_{501} & \le & 24        \\
-6.94e-17 & \le & N_{502} & \le & 2.78e-16  \\
-24       & \le & N_{511} & \le & 4         \\
-2.78e-16 & \le & N_{512} & \le & 6.94e-17  \\
          &     & D_{500} & =   & 4         \\
-1        & \le & D_{501} & \le & 0         \\
2.78e-7   & \le & D_{511} & \le & 1
\end{array}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]